# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, plpgsql

I am developing an asp.net a data and i wold insert a data in one column. I'm using this code in postgresql it say that but it gives me this error. Can you help me?

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression SQL state: 21000

```
SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point (route.geom,(select (pk_accident)/(pk_fin-pk_debut) from route, accident_ma 
where route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route order by route.num_route))
from route,accident_ma where route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route order by route.num_route;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ST_Line_Interpolate_Point*** is scalar function it was design to get as an input set of two values .

The in-select-query ***"SELECT (pk_accident)/(pk_fin-pk_debut)
                                     FROM route, accident_ma
                                     WHERE route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
                                     ORDER BY route.num_route "***

suppose to return one value per selected  records (this value will be used by the ST_Line_Interpolate_Point function )  , however  in-select-query  return more then one record   .

In Oracle you can modify your query by adding  additional filter

***"And rownum=1"*** filter ,  for none oracle cases you can add ***limit 1***  filter

***select (pk_accident)/(pk_fin-pk_debut)
                                     FROM route, accident_ma
                                     WHERE route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
                                    limit 1***

This should fix the problem

Comment: but if i do limit 1 it return 1 values but i would excute the request for all the table

Comment: The limit is only on  the sub query , your query ->  :SELECT ST_Line_Interpolate_Point (route.geom,
                                    (SELECT (pk_accident)/(pk_fin-pk_debut)
                                     FROM route, accident_ma
                                     WHERE route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
                                      limit 1 ))
FROM route,
     accident_ma
WHERE route.num_route = accident_ma.num_route
ORDER BY route.num_route;